# Listbox from the second sheet

Tags: excel

Need some help in creating a listbox on the first sheet using the column headers on the second sheets. I the want to use the selected values from the listbox to delete the relevant columns of data from the second sheet. I am completely lost - HELP

Comment: The Listbox is Data, Data Validation, Data Validation, List. The amount of effort to select a column header from the Listbox and press a button or key combination to run a macro will be very similar to Deleting the column manually. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA solution.

```
Sub PopulateListBox()
    Dim ListBox As MSForms.ListBox, columnHeaders As Range, header As Range

    Set ListBox = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListBox1
    Set columnHeaders = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C1")

    ListBox.Clear

    For Each header In columnHeaders
        ListBox.AddItem (header)
    Next header
End Sub

Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim headerIndex As Integer, selectedHeader As Integer

    For headerIndex = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(headerIndex) = True Then
            DeleteColumn ListBox1.List(headerIndex)
        End If
    Next headerIndex

    PopulateListBox
End Sub

Sub DeleteColumn(headerId As String)
    Dim ListBox As MSForms.ListBox, columnHeaders As Range, header As Range

    Set columnHeaders = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C1")

    For Each header In columnHeaders
        If header = headerId Then
            header.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next header
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. Add a `Forms.ListBox` on to your sheet (`sheet1` in my example) and populate it with column headers (found on `sheet2` in `A1:C1` in my example)
2. When a user clicks a header in the `ListBox` then the column is deleted and the `ListBox` updates to remove that column as a selection
3. You will need to tweak the range references accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that. it gave me a Run Time error ;438'. Object does not support this property or methof

Comment: Which line did you get error on? It worked on my machine.

Comment: Set ListBox = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListBox1

Comment: Typo . Now get subscript out of range on next line

Comment: sorted. Is it oissible to make the range dynamic to cater fir extra columns if data being added

Comment: Yes. Look at end(xlRight) or Columns.Count. If you search this site for dynamic range using VBA you will get lots of information.